# Multithreaded Haskell

Tags: multithreading, haskell, parallel-processing, multicore

I'm learning Haskell and I'd like to write some multithreaded programs now to see the performance gains from that in a functional language. I can find some references to it on the internet but never a proper introduction to it. Can anyone point me to a guide which is understandable for someone who knows the syntax fairly well, but is not a wizard in Haskell?

Comment: You get gains from immutability at the implementation level in multi-thread programming. Just because a language is pure doesn't mean that the data is not mutated - the actual value in the memory location must be written once and once only. Haskell is lazy, so YMMV - performance becomes very sensitive to how a thunk caches its value, and whether this requires a bus lock, or places a burden on the compiler to prevent lazy values being shared.  A strict functional language might be a better place to look for performance. (Bastien's link shows forcing of shared values)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I gave a 3 hour course on this topic at DEFUN 2009. The slides and code are online: [Multicore Haskell Now!](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2009/09/05/defun-2009-multicore-programming-in-haskell-now/)

Comment: The link itself is not dead, but the source and slide links within the link are dead.

Answer (score 5):

Have you read Real Word Haskell?
http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html

Answer (score 5):

I think the paper "A Tutorial on Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell" is the perfect starting point for you. You can find it here:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/parallel/index.htm